# Law of large numbers for sum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem

Liz is standing on the real number line at position 0. She rolls a die repeatedly. If the roll is 1 or 2, she takes one step to the right (in the positive direction). If the roll is 3, 4, 5 or 6, she takes two steps to the right. Let $X_n$ be Liz's position after n flips. Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n>1,6n)$$

I determined a random variable N as the number of rolls that give 1,2. Then $N\sim Bin(n,\frac{1}{3})$. $X_n=N+2(n−N)$. My question is: what is the distribution of $X_n$, how to apply Law of Large Numbers?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
To apply the law of large numbers to a series $\sum_n A_n$, you don't need the distribution of $A_n$, just variance and expectation. Here too,
$$
X_n = \sum_{k=1}^n A_k, \quad \text{with} \quad
A_k = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{ with probability } 1/3,\\
2, & \text{ with probability } 2/3.
\end{cases}
$$
Can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

$$X_n = 2n -N$$

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n > 1.6n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty}P(2n-N>1.6n) \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}P(N < 0.4n)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(N - \frac{n}3 < \frac{n}{15}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[1- P\left(N - \frac{n}3 \ge \frac{n}{15}\right) \right]\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[1- P\left(\frac{N - \frac{n}3}{\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{3}} \ge \frac{\frac{n}{15}}{\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{3}}\right) \right]\\
&\ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ 1- \left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{3}}{\frac{n}{15}}\right)^2\right] \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} [1- \frac{50}{n}]
\end{align}

Comment: I used [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)